# In Objective-C, what happens to the original object when the init method sets self?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, inheritance, class, initialization

I have three Objective-C classes:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject{
     IBOutlet id<ClassAProtocol>delegate
     //other instance variables
}

//methods
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA{
     //instance variables
}

//methods
@end

@interface ClassC : ClassA{
     //instance variables
}

//methods
@end
```

My objective is so that when an instance of `ClassA` is called for in either code or InterfaceBuilder, an instance of `ClassB` or `ClassC` is actually created. Whether it will be `ClassB` or `ClassC` depends on a return value of a method in `ClassAProtocol` as implemented by the `delegate` object.

```
@implementation ClassA

static BOOL _initFromSubclass = NO;

-(id)init{
     if(_initFromSubclass){
          _initFromSubclass = NO;
          self = [super init];
     }else {
          _initFromSubclass = YES;
          if([delegate shouldInitClassB]){
                self = [[ClassB alloc] init];
          }else{
                self = [[ClassC alloc] init];
          }
     }

     return self;
}

//other methods
@end
```

This doesn't work the way I wanted because at the init call, the delegate (set in Interface Builder) is still nil, and so the object created is always `ClassC`.  Also, a `ClassA` object is created first, then, in its init call, creates a new `ClassC` object, with a different memory address, and no `ClassA` object is dealloced. I have three questions:

1)What happens to the original `ClassA` object? (I think it's leaked, but I want to know).

2)How do I avoid the leak?

3)How do I accomplish what I actually want? By the time the delegate is set (say, in `awakeFromNib` method), it's too late to reset the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes I think it will be leaked because it has a retain count of +1 after the `alloc` but nothing will release it.
2. You can use `[self release]` before reassigning the value of `self`. Some argue that it should be `[self dealloc]` directly, but I personally prefer the former.
3. Objects instantiated from nibs are sent `initWithCoder:` messages I think, so override that instead of `init`. Although, at this point, I'm still not sure whether `delegate` will be set.

Comment: Are you sure about that 3rd one? For `initWithCoder:` to work, the class needs to implement the `NSCoding` protocol, which NSObject by default does not, and neither do my classes, but I have no problem creating instances of any of them in InterfaceBuilder. Also, when I create `ClassA` in IB, it goes through that init call I posted above twice -- first as itself, then as a call to `[super init]` from `ClassC`.